# JQ - parsing field by hierarchy

Tags: json, bash, addition, jq

I have very large json I want to extract sum of data from it using jq.

I am trying every possible way but I think I am missing something here..

My Json subset:

```
{"main":
  {"0": {"x": {"a":1}, "y": {"number of un-used":{"count":2} , "z":2}},
  "1": {"x": {"a":1}, "y": {"number of un-used":{"count":3} , "z":2}},
  "2": {"x": {"a":1}, "y": {"number of un-used":{"count":4} , "z":2}},
  "3": {"x": {"a":1}, "y": {"no un-used":{"z":3} , "z":2}},
  "4": {"x": {"a":1}, "y": {"no un-used":{"z":3} , "z":2}}},
 "no-main":
  {"0": {"x": {"a":1}, "y": {"number of un-used":{"count":2} , "z":2}},
  "1": {"x": {"a":1}, "y": {"number of un-used":{"count":3} , "z":2}},
  "2": {"x": {"a":1}, "y": {"number of un-used":{"count":4} , "z":2}},
  "3": {"x": {"a":1}, "y": {"no un-used":{"z":3} , "z":2}},
  "4": {"x": {"a":1}, "y": {"no un-used":{"z":3} , "z":2}}}}
```

I want the sum of "count" - "number of un-used" that is under "y".

My most successful one is:

```
cat json | jq '.[] | .[].y | .["number of un-used"] | .count'
```

But the results contains a lot of "null" because "number of un-used" is not in all of "y" dicts..

Is it solvable?

Comment: @Inian - Fixed, Thanks.

Comment: What is your expected output for JSON in question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add zero to a null to get ... zero.

```
jq '.[] | .[].y | ."number of un-used" | .count + 0' < input.json
```

This produces the list of `count` values you're looking for, with the `null` values showing `0`. Adding them to your sum should not change it.

`jq` can do basic arithmetic in its expressions, but having it calculate your sum internally gets a little more complex. While you can define a function that uses a `reduce`, it would probably be easier to sum these values by appending something to the command line like this:

```
| awk '{n+=$1}END{print n}'
```

Of course, there's a zillion ways you could add up numbers, some more hackish than others.

```
$ { printf '%s+' $(jq '.[] | .[].y | ."number of un-used" | .count + 0' input.json); echo 0; } | bc
18
```

Comment: Also note that `.[] | .[].y` could be written as `.main[].y.`

Comment: @Inian, thanks, yes that works for the first half of the input in the question, but the other other half, the object associated with the `no-main` string, then gets missed. If you want to handle *all* pairs in the enclosing object, I think the pipe notation is the right way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Since the JSON is very large, you might want a solution that is overall quite efficient, so it would be worthwhile considering the following:

```
def sigma(s): reduce s as $x (0; .+$x);
sigam(.[].[].y | .["number of un-used"] | .count)
```

Notice that this also addresses the problem with nulls. To make the solution even more robust, you could sprinkle in some occurrences of post-fix `?` as well.

For humomgously large JSON, you might need a streaming solution, but that would be considerably more complicated, though the above def would still be applicable.

Answer (score 0):

If the JSON is too large to fit comfortably in memory, then jq's streaming parser could be used, as illustrated here.

#### Invocation

```
$ jq -n --stream -f program.jq input.json
```

Note especially the "-n" option.

#### program.jq

```
def sigma(s): reduce s as $x (0; .+$x);

sigma(inputs 
      | select(length==2) 
      | select(.[0][-3:] == ["y","number of un-used","count"])
      | .[1] )
```